# Processing files from S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I need to do some processing of files stored on S3, namely warc files from here: http://commoncrawl.org/2016/05/april-2016-crawl-archive-now-available/

I tried to do this in a Spark application running on Amazon machine with 7.5RAM by passing a comma-separated list of these gz-files to sc.textFile().
The application failed after processing 15 files (there are 22200 gz-files in total, each gz-file is close to 1GB, and its content is a file with size roughly 4GB). It failed reporting there wasn't enough RAM. It failed even when I set to use only 1 core:

```
by val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[1]")
```

I think it's because each archive is downloaded, extracted in RAM, and only then its processing starts. 'top' shows that 80% of RAM is consumed by a java process. When I run the application on a local machine and some gz-files are on the same computer, no problem occurs.

If the application could download a portion of a gz-file, extract this portion, process, discard, download the next portion and so on, available RAM should be enough...

What ideas/functions/tools would you suggest for this processing?

P.S. Error-log produced by Spark: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3TXiTrxstmHeGh2cUJ1VnhyUGM/view?usp=sharing

The code:

```
// Having run in 'library' directory
//   mvn clean install
// run the following to create a jar file
//   mvn clean package
// Then you can run a resulting jar file to process all warc.gz files in a directory
// provided as the first agrument for the application like this way
//   java -jar spark-cortex-fat.jar /media/bj/d08da197-87a1-4ca4-a8c0-c1527570b384/commoncrawl
// or to process all dumps from http://commoncrawl.org/ listed in remoteDumpsList like this way
//   java -jar spark-cortex-fat.jar XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
// where XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY are your access key ID and secret access key
// for your AWS Account (this time it's preferable to run it on AWS in order to avoid downloading commoncrawl dumps)

package com.qbeats.cortex

import java.io.File
import java.net.URL
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.nio.channels.Channels
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.util.Date
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SparkCortex extends App {
  var defaulTime = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse("Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT")

  def dropFirst(partitionIndex: Int, iterator: Iterator[String]): Iterator[String] = {
    if (partitionIndex == 0 && iterator.hasNext) {
      iterator.next
      iterator
    } else
      iterator
    }

  def tryExtractTime(timeString: String, timeFormatStrings: List[String]): Date = {
    if (!timeFormatStrings.isEmpty) {
      val timeFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(timeFormatStrings(0))
      try {
        return timeFormat.parse(timeString)
      } catch {
        case _: Throwable => {
          return tryExtractTime(timeString, timeFormatStrings.tail)
        }
      }
    } else {
      return defaulTime
    }
  }

  def extractTime(timeString: String): Date = {
    val timeFormatStrings = List(
      "M/d/yyyy K:mm:ss a",
      "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
      "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
      "E, d-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX",
      "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy z",
      "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy",
      "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
      "EEE, MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
      "EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '(UTC)'"
    )
    return tryExtractTime(timeString, timeFormatStrings)
  }

   def extractMetadata(entity: String): (String, Date, Date, Int) = {
    val requestTimePattern = """WARC-Date: (.+)""".r  // -> static field
    val requestTimeString = requestTimePattern.findFirstMatchIn(entity).map(_ group 1).get
    val requestTimeFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    val requestTime = requestTimeFormat.parse(requestTimeString)

    val modifiedTimePattern = """Last-Modified: (.+)""".r  // -> static field
    val modifiedTimeString = modifiedTimePattern.findFirstMatchIn(entity).map(_ group 1).getOrElse("")
    val modifiedTime = extractTime(modifiedTimeString)

    val urlPattern = """WARC-Target-URI: https?://([^/?]+)/.*""".r  // -> static field
    val url = urlPattern.findFirstMatchIn(entity).map(_ group 1).getOrElse("")

    (url, requestTime, modifiedTime, entity.size)
  }

  def processFile(fileNames: Array[String], accessKeyId: String = "", secretAccessKey: String = ""): Unit = {
    defaulTime = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse("Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT")
    val appName = "CortexSpark"
    val master = "local[*]"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    if (!accessKeyId.isEmpty) sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId)
    if (!secretAccessKey.isEmpty) sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", secretAccessKey)
    val delimiter = "WARC/1.0\r\nWARC-Type: request"
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", delimiter)

    val entities = sc.
      textFile(fileNames.mkString(",")).
      mapPartitionsWithIndex(dropFirst).
      map(delimiter + _).
      map(extractMetadata).  // todo: delete
      cache()

    // Save host histogram
    entities.filter(!_._1.isEmpty).map(a => (a._1, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).coalesce(1).sortBy(_._2).saveAsTextFile("hosts")

    // Save request time histogram
    entities.map(a => (a._2, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).coalesce(1).sortBy(_._2).saveAsTextFile("request_times")

    // Save modified time histogram
    entities.filter(_._3 != defaulTime).map(a => (a._3, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).coalesce(1).sortBy(_._2).
      saveAsTextFile("modified_times")

    // Save size histogram
    entities.map(a => (a._4, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).coalesce(1).sortBy(_._2).saveAsTextFile("sizes")

    println("Number of entities: " + entities.count)

    sc.stop
  }

  def getUrls(fileToDownload: String): Array[String] = {
    var urls = Array[String]()
    val url = new URL(fileToDownload)
    val responseCode = url.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection].getResponseCode
    if (responseCode == 200) {
      val channel = Channels.newChannel(new GZIPInputStream(new URL(fileToDownload).openStream()))
      val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(5 * 1024 * 1024)
      channel.read(buffer)
      val data = new String(buffer.array()).trim()
      urls = data.split('\n').map("s3n://commoncrawl/" + _)
    }
    return urls
  }

  def getLocalFiles(directory: String): Array[String] = {
    val d = new File(directory)
    if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
      return d.listFiles.map(_.getAbsolutePath).filter(_.endsWith("warc.gz"))
    } else {
      return Array[String]()
    }
  }

  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val remoteDumpsList = "https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-18/warc.paths.gz"
    if  (args.length > 0) {
      if (args(0).contains(':')) {
        val urls = getUrls(remoteDumpsList)
        val s3Credentials = args(0).split(':')
        processFile(urls, s3Credentials(0), s3Credentials(1))
      } else {
        val files = getLocalFiles(args(0))
        processFile(files)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you precise spark.driver.memory and spark.executor.memory ?

Comment: gzipped files are not splittable, meaning all the processing happens on single node and you practically don't have parallelism.

Comment: Strange, today I started the script again, and now it is processing files seamlessly (with only 19% RAM used by java). The only change is that I acquired the sudo privileges (via 'sudo su').

@koffee, I use defaults in Spark 1.6.1.

Avihoo Mamka, I'm okay with this because I've got 22200 files, and parallelism is achieved by different threads processing different files.

Comment: The problems still exists. I attached the code and error-log. Could someone help?

Comment: I've managed to solve this problem simply by increasing maximum Java heap size in the command running the application.